# How can I animate height to auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**jQuery**

```
$(".facts").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).height() >50) {
    $(this).animate({height:50+'px'});
    $(this).find('.servicedrop').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    $(this).removeClass("facts_active");
  }else{
    if ( $(".facts_active").length) {
      $(".facts_active").animate({height:50+'px'});
    }
    $(this).animate({height:350 + 'px'});
    $(this).find('.servicedrop').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
    $(this).addClass("facts_active");
  }
});
```

Instead of animating to the `height:350px`, I want to animate the `height` to `"auto"`, to make my accordion responsive. I googled it and read some solutions, but I don't know how to add it to the code.

It would be so nice of you to help me.

Comment: Quite simply, you can't animate to `height: auto`. The best you can do is animate the `max-height` property from 0 to 100%, which has its own quirks.

Comment: So there is no chance to use the animate function on a responsive website? :/

Comment: It's possible by computing height dynamically using $('select').height();
Please refer to the posted answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't animate to `height:auto;` but you can get around it by animating `max-height` and setting the active `max-height` to a value you know will never be exceeded. You can also do it with far less Javascript as the animation can be handled with CSS3:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.facts').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.facts {
  width:300px;
  max-height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
  .facts.active {
    max-height:9999px; /*Height value which will not be exceeded*/
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
<div class="facts">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus erat justo, eu sagittis enim consequat id. Donec luctus luctus aliquam. Curabitur libero neque, interdum in nulla at, semper malesuada ligula. Donec tincidunt ipsum sit amet libero euismod, vel placerat est elementum. Fusce rhoncus molestie venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus rhoncus nisl nisl, sit amet suscipit est ultrices non. Nunc odio massa, tincidunt scelerisque venenatis sed, scelerisque nec leo.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by computing the height dynamically using `$('select').height();`

```
$(".facts").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).height() >50) {
    $(this).animate({height:50+'px'});
    $(this).find('.servicedrop').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    $(this).removeClass("facts_active");
  }else{
    if ( $(".facts_active").length) {
      $(".facts_active").animate({height:50+'px'});
    }
    var computedH =  $(this).height(); // compute div's height including content
    $(this).animate({height: computedH + 'px'}); // now you can animate the computed height

    $(this).find('.servicedrop').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
    $(this).addClass("facts_active");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like on this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/pparas/frw0opfv/6/

You will have to calculate the height that you want and then animate it.

```
$(".facts").click(function(e) {
    var newHeight = $('div.inner').height();
    $(this).animate({
        height: newHeight
    });
});
```

Something similar to @Arun Sharma's reply.

Hope that helps.

Paras